# ManyToMany DQL from working SQL, accessing OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

A working application uses a native SQL query to get items from a ManyToMany Entity relationship.  Attempts to translate that query end up in a myriad of error messages.  The Household entity has a ManyToMany relationship with Reason. Both entities & their relationships are properly defined.  The joining table (*household_reason*) is not defined in .../Entity.  The part that eludes me is how to join the Contact entity, with which the Household entity has a OneToMany relationship.

The working SQL:

```
    select distinct r.reason
    from reason r
    join household_reason hr on hr.reason_id = r.id
    join household h on h.id = hr.household_id
    join contact c on c.household_id = h.id...
```

For starters, here's the beginning of a query builder in the Reason repository:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')->select('distinct r.reason')
    ->innerJoin('r.households', 'h')
```

Now that there's the plural `households`, how to I specify a relationship to a singular household?

Answer (score 0):

Took a while, but the following works:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')->select('distinct r.reason')
        ->innerJoin('r.households', 'h')
        ->innerJoin('TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Contact', 'c', 'WITH c.household = h.household')
        ->where('c.contactDate >= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('c.contactDate <= :endDate')
        ->andWhere('r.enabled = TRUE')
        ->orderBy('r.id')
        ->setParameters($dateCriteria)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```